# Please synonym vbs to vbscript

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please synonym [vbs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vbs) to [vbscript](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vbscript).

Comment: How long does it take before the Synonymizer badge is awarded? I thought it would have been added to my profile by now.

Answer (score 2):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)