# Synonymizer badge not showing in my profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, retag-request

[I suggested a tag synonym](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2583/please-synonym-vbs-to-vbscript) several days ago which was accepted, but I haven't yet been awarded the Synonymizer badge. When will this badge appear in my profile? I thought it would have appeared by now.

Answer (score 7):

The badge is only awarded through creating a tag synonym through the [tag system](https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms) (which requires 2500 rep and 5 votes in the tag), not recommending one in meta.

Comment: Thanks. I had several more to suggest, but I will wait until I get enough rep and can do it the right way.

Comment: @Starish: The badges aren't important. If you have synonyms to suggest that will make SF better then the best thing to do is get on with it.

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon Shane's question, the *official* tag synonym system is not, "Post to meta, have a mod do it." It actually involves having enough rep to suggest a synonym, and having enough users upvote the synonym that it becomes an official synonym.

This can be short-circuited by suggesting a synonym via the official system, and then a mod later approves the synonym.

Because of the reputation requirements for synonyms, I believe this method is the only way this badge is being earned these days. The synonym system was written for SO, and even though we're the #3 site for traffic, it doesn't work for us as written; the mods end up doing all of the synonym creation.

Comment: How does one suggest it via the official system so it can be approved by a mod? Despite extensive searching, I couldn't find out how one officially suggests one. There are no buttons or links to suggest or create one. I only found people suggesting them here which I thought was the official way.

Comment: @Starfish Example, go [here](http://serverfault.com/tags/apache2/synonyms). If you have enough rep, there is a "Suggest a [apache2] synonym:" entry at the bottom. All the tag synonyms are listed [here](http://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms). The rep requirements are two-fold. You need 2500 to even try, and a certain amount *in the tag* to suggest one.

Comment: I don't see a suggest button, only a link to see all tag synonyms. I'm still trying to understand your comment *"Because of the reputation requirements for synonyms, I believe this method is the only way this badge is being earned these days."* How can someone do that if they can't even suggest the synonym until they have 2500 rep? If they have 2500 rep then rep would not longer be a limiting factor as that sentence suggests. I'm confused. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Starfish If you look at the "top users" tab for a tag, you'll get a list of the top rep-earners in that tag. It also gives you the number of upvotes you've earned in the tag. The whole system is documented here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work/70718#70718

Comment: @Starfish They key problem is that to suggest a synonym you need 2500 rep **in the tag itself**. That's a Bronze tag-badge at least, and well on the way to a silver tag-badge. This means that the only way to clean up 'minor' tags (in our case, anything that isn't a top-20 tag) is to do it via Meta and have a mod do it. The 'synomizer' badge is one that is nigh impossible to earn now. Those that have it now did so before the rules changed for the worst.

Comment: We'll discuss if changes are needed around how tag synonyms are suggested.

Comment: This is what the tag synonym pages say the requirements are. **Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.**